# what is the equvalent control for "C# properties" in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

In C# there are

> Get or Set properties

present,Is there any similar control in objetive c?

Answer (score 1):

They are called properties, like in C#. In .NET, the getter for a property Foo is called get_Foo and the setter set_Foo, although C# hides that fact for you. Objective C doesn't necessarily hide that, although the mechanism is similar.

In Objective-C, you declare it as

```
@property NSString *foo; // I omitted property attributes here, see link
```

You can either write your own getters and setters:

```
- (NSString *) foo;
- (void) setFoo: (NSString *) value;
```

Or you let the compiler do that for you:

```
@synthesize foo;
```

More here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html